# Keyboard buttons disappear and keyboard rendered wrong on iOS9

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I'm getting reports of keys disappearing or becoming invisible on iPhone native keyboard and have also seen this happen on my iPhone 4S. The keyboard is setup for dark appearance decimal pad.

The bug is typically accompanied by this message.

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 4131139949_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

The problem seems to go away if I background the app and open another app and then come back.

As you can see in the screenshot the background of the keys also seems to be wrong for "dark" setting.

[Snapshot of missing keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG6Jr.png)